# Collation Problem - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to understand this error I'm getting on a SQL Server 2005 instance. Error below:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict
>   between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI" in the
>   equal to operation.

Both databases included in a simple query have **Latin1 General CI AI**, but had **SQL Latin1 General CP1 CI AI** before. I changed the collation trying to match them but still get the aforementioned error every time I try to join a temp table with a table from a user database. I have no issues creating temp tables.

Comment: Precisely what I'm trying to understand is why I'm getting the error if both my temp database and my user database have the same Collation option.

Comment: I got my problem semi-solved by adding COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT after the join that was causing the collation issue. I was able to make the query work that way but I'm still puzzled by this collation issue as I'm not completely understanding what's causing the problem

Comment: interesting that you say the database_default solved your problem but you accepted a different answer ;)

Comment: I applied the collate command on the join rather than on the column property definition, as you suggested. I thought my accepted answer got it closer although you were on the same line. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you join you can use COLLATE to change the collation on the fly to make them the same:

```
select c.name, o.orderid from customer as c
inner join order as o on c.custid = o.custid COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```

Assuming that cust is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI and order is some other collation, the above query will fix the problem.

Comment: Even though you changed the database collation, the object collation is still the old one. Right click on the table, go to properties. You will see it's on the old collation.

Comment: I did as you mention. As far as the Properties Page shows, the database objects inherited the correct collation setting, which is what's confusing me. It seems it's only happening with temp tables.

Comment: Changing a database collation by default does not change the collcations of the objects within. So it' strange that they got the new collations, unless they were created after teh DB collcation changed. In which case anyway it must be the collcation of TempDB - where temporay tables are placed.

Answer (score 3):

Look in the table design that both fields you do the join have the same collation settings.

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
ALTER COLUMN <column> VARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
GO
```

Comment: It's better to alter the column collation like tricat proposes, because sometimes the collate instruction in the query is not enough because of differences in the SQL Server configuration when the application is deployed

Answer (score 2):

> If you create a temp table and your
>   database has a different collation
>   other than TempDB (which has the same
>   collation as the system - based on
>   installation), then
>   comparisons/lookups/joins - may have
>   problems. A simple trick to get around
>   this is to use database_default:

```
CREATE TABLE #test2
(
   col1 varchar(12) COLLATE database_default
)
go
```

Re. [Changing Database Collation and dealing with TempDB Objects](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Changing-Database-Collation-and-dealing-with-TempDB-Objects.aspx)

**Did you rebuild all indexes after changing the Database's collation order?**

Comment: What if both my tempDB has the same collation as the database I'm trying to join with?

Comment: You may have changed the database collation, but that does not change the collation of the objects in the datase. Right click on the table, go to properties. You will see it has the old collation.

Comment: I did not rebuild all indexes.

Comment: You should rebuild all indexes after changing a database's collation order.

Answer (score 1):

I've run across very similar-sounding problems when moving a database between servers with different collations. The database comes across with it's original collation, but because the new server's collation (and hence the tempdb database's collation) is different, it causes problems when I create a temp table and try to join with it.

If you're saying that your database's collation is the same as the server's collation, then I guess you must have some columns that are using a different collation. (You can change the collation on a column-by-column basis).

Anyway, I always deal with these problems simply by changing the collation of the whole database to match the target server after restoring it. That's a PITA to do manually, but luckily there's a [tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ChangeCollation.aspx) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, if you are using an in-memory tempDb, it gets recreated as needed. Thus, if your **Model** database has a different collation, a new created db (like tempDb) will inherit it from Model.

Comment: tempDB always inherits the collation of Model regardless of whether its in-memory (which very few are).